# trying to change direction but it dosent work (

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to add dir=rtl or direction: rtl to the css, but it dosent affect the browser and the content id display ltr altogether.  what can i do?

this is a ready made template from colorlib. free html\css templates. 
10x

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="other-feature-item">
        <i class="ti-key"></i>
        <h4>title</h4>
        <div>
          <p>
            content
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the css directive you are using to change the text direction?

Comment: i am trying to add dir="rtl" directly to the P or div.  or, to the class="direction: rtl .... col-lg etc".    both cases dosent do anything and the text remain ltr

Comment: In order to help you please open account in https://codepen.io/ (it's free), put all code there, and edit the question with a link.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a general class element in your CSS and add that class to the html element:

```
.text-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Then your html element would be as follows:

```
<p class="text-rtl">Right to Left Text</p>
```

Comment: i know that :-)  but u already have a bunch of class and css files.  i tried directly to write  <div class="direction: rtl" class="original class">. the results was that the text remain ltr by default and the original div class was disregarded.

Comment: @EitanCapital I don't think I fully understand but you cannot have two **class** attributes on the same element, you can place all the class names in one attribute seperated by spaces. Also, in `class="direction: rtl"`, `direction: rtl` is not a valid class name.